# With powershell, how do I find out which user is running a service?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, service, windows-service

As mentioned in the title, how to find out which user is running a service with powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get this through WMI:

```
$serviceName = "EventSystem"
$svc = Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -eq $serviceName}
$svc.StartName
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
gwmi win32_service | ForEach-Object { 

$process=$_.ProcessId
$name=$_.Displayname
if($process -ne 0)
{
Write-Host "Service: $name - ID: $process"
(gwmi -class win32_process | where{$_.ProcessID -eq $process }).getowner() | Select -property domain, user }
}
```

Haven't tested it a lot, but gives me what I need.